# Filtering in pandas by user giving input date and n +/- dates around it?

Tags: python, pandas, filtering

I'm still relatively new to this so for this one I have no code just a question.

Is it possible to filter data in a data frame by user input. For example, I have a huge data frame where I have the daily stock prices of many companies. I would like to just get the prices by a specific date and then n - number of dates around it. I know it is possible to specify a start and end date, but I have a huge timeframe and a lot of companies. So for every company, **I would like to specify a t0 (input) and then get for example +20 days and - 10 days around to.**

```
        DATE           SP500     pct_c
1541    2021-01-15  3768.246290 NaN
1542    2021-01-19  3798.907531 0.008137
1543    2021-01-20  3851.845936 0.013935
1544    2021-01-21  3853.073298 0.000319
1545    2021-01-22  3841.465571 -0.003013
1546    2021-01-25  3855.355735 0.003616
1547    2021-01-26  3849.621265 -0.001487
1548    2021-01-27  3750.773205 -0.025677
1549    2021-01-28  3787.376856 0.009759
1550    2021-01-29  3714.242690 -0.019310
```

Thanks to everyone who might provide some insight, and I apologise for the mess of the explanation.

Edited: added data frame. For example is it possible that user specifies a certain date and then we filter the data frame by having only input values +/- n values around it? And maybe even create a loop for this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas can work with datetime columns / indeces:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html#pandas.DatetimeIndex

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/offset_frequency.html

You can use this to select data based on seconds, minutes, days, months etc.

Getting the user input can be done by a gui like easygui_qt.get_date()